# Execute powershell command from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I trying to execute this powershell command from C#

```
gci C:\Ditectory -Recurse | unblock-file -whatif
```

using this code

```
        Runspace space = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        space.Open();
        space.SessionStateProxy.Path.SetLocation(directoryPath);
        Pipeline pipeline = space.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.Add("get-childitem");

        pipeline.Commands.Add("Unblock-File");
        pipeline.Commands.Add("-whatif");
        var cresult = pipeline.Invoke();
        space.Close();
```

I keep getting an exception about the whatif not being recognized command.
Can I use whatif from C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WhatIf` is a parameter not a command, so it should be added to the Parameters collection of the command object for `Unblock-File`. However, this is made awkward by the API which returns void from `Commands.Add`. I suggest a using a small set of helper extension methods which will allow you to use a builder-like syntax:

```
internal static class CommandExtensions
{
    public static Command AddCommand(this Pipeline pipeline, string command)
    {
        var com = new Command(command);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(com);
        return com;
    }

    public static Command AddParameter(this Command command, string parameter)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(parameter));
        return command;
    }

    public static Command AddParameter(this Command command, string parameter, object value)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(parameter, value));
        return command;
    }
}
```

Then your code is simple:

```
pipeline.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem").AddParameter("Recurse");
pipeline.AddCommand("Unblock-File").AddParameter("WhatIf");
var results = pipeline.Invoke();
space.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the extension methods, I have tried them and I still cannot see the result. I Modified the code to add the path to the Get-ChildItem but no dice
Pipeline pipeline = space.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem").AddParameter("Path",dlg.SelectedPath).AddParameter("Recurse");
                pipeline.AddCommand("Unblock-File").AddParameter("WhatIf");
                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
                var results = pipeline.Invoke();

Comment: @user3373870 It looks like the output of `WhatIf` does not go to the pipeline and is sent directly to the host. Therefore you need to implement your own `PSHostUserInterface` object. From what I can tell this is a non-trivial undertaking. Best to ask another question after you've done some research.

Comment: found out why the script was failing.
Intelitrace is showing + Caught: "Unable to load DLL 'wldp.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" (System.DllNotFoundException)

Answer (score 1):

Whatif is a parameter, not a command. Try the `AddParameter` method instead:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182433(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)